# zipme implementation in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want to apply unzipping the file using zipme cn1 library (codenameone library). Is there any examples on how to do it? Can anyone give me the starting point? So far I have tried the following code but I am not sure where to keep dataName.zip file in the project and the folder to keep all the files after unzipping.

```
@Override
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {
    net.sf.zipme.ZipEntry dataZE;
    InputStream isData = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + "dataName" + ".zip");
    StringBuffer sbData = new StringBuffer();
    ZipInputStream dataZIS = new ZipInputStream(isData);
    try {
        while ((dataZE = dataZIS.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            //how to extract the zip file in a separate folder...
            dataZIS.closeEntry();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("zip exception");
    }
}
```

The above code gives following error:

```
    cannot find symbol
    InputStream isData = getClass().getResourceAsStream("");
    symbol:   method getResourceAsStream(String)
```

One more thing, why cant I use the following to get the zip file as in core java

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\abc.zip"));
    // it gives "FileInputStream: cannot find symbol"
```

How can I extract the zip file in a separate folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream()`.

`FileInputStream` isn't supported in Codename One which uses `FileSystemStorage`. The `FileInputStream` and `File` API's assume many things about the underlying OS that aren't always true.

Comment: thanks and how can I extract the zip into a folder? Is there any eg in cn1 for doing it? I thought that fileOutputStream will do but it is also not supported as fileInputStream. FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(dataZE.getName()); 
                for (int c = dataZIS.read(); c != -1; c = dataZIS.read()) {
                    fout.write(c);
                }
                dataZIS.closeEntry();
                fout.close();

Comment: You need to use FileSystemStorage which supports folders. There is no example at the moment as zip support is brand new.

Comment: How to extract the zip file? Can you give me smth to start with? Thankyou

Comment: It's just like the JavaSE API only you need to use the FileSystemStorage API to create the output stream and directory. Notice that unlike File/FileInputStream the FileSystemStorage API always requires full paths. There are samples of working with FileSystemStorage in the developer guide https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html